# Expiration header for all files in a specific folder (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, cache-expiration

For all files, except pdf, in a specific directory as well as its sub-directories on the server, I would like to set the expiration header to 10 hours. How can I do this in the .htaccess file?

```
<Directory "/foldername">
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresByType * "access plus 10 hours"
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I understand `Directory` cannot be used in .htaccess. But how to do this?

Comment: Put the .htaccess _into_ the "specific directory", and do it in there without any further restriction?

Comment: Or wrap it into an `If` instead, that checks that the request URI starts with your folder name. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, so if I put the .htaccess file in the folder, it will automatically apply to its subfolders? And is `ExpiresByType * ` correct, i.e., is the * allowed?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically apply to subfolders. `ExpiresByType *` won't work though, according to documentation the first argument needs to be a mime type. But [`ExpiresDefault`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresdefault) also exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the .htaccess into the specific directory, and do it in there without any further restriction. Or use an `If` condition, to apply this based on what the request URI starts with.

`ExpiresByType *` won't work, according to the documentation, this needs an actual mime type as "argument".

But [`ExpiresDefault`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresdefault) also exists, and allows you to specify the default expiry for all files.

Comment: At a folder higher, there's also a `.htaccess` file that sets the expiration data per mime type, including a default. So I essentially need to overwrite those settings for this specific folder. To this end, I've also specified the expiration per mime type in the `htaccess` file in the specific folder. It works for the mime types not specified a level higher up, but for those that are now in both `htaccess` files, the configuration from the `htaccess` at a folder higher up, seems to take precedent. How to change this?

Comment: Those you will have to override explicitly then. The default applies only for those types, that did not have any specific value configured yet.

Comment: In the `.htaccess` in the specific folder, I have: `<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 6 hours"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 6 hours"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>`

But still the expiration header for css and js files (in a subfolder of the specific folder) is equal to that set in the `htaccess` at the higher level.

Comment: _"(in a subfolder of the specific folder)"_ - and directly in the folder itself? Since these settings should "inherit" further down, this rather sounds like your configuration did not properly apply to begin with.

Comment: I looked and also directly in the specific folder itself, it's still using the setting of the `htaccess` that exists a folder up, instead of the one in the specific folder. But this must be a separate issue, if you have any suggestions I very much welcome them, but I'll already accept the answer.